# "The role manager feature has not been enabled" error during unit testing of SQL Server Role Provider

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, roleprovider

I have a class library I'm using to wrap the SQL Server Membership and Role provider API's. I attempted to test my first method in my MSTest unit test class, but I got the error, "The role manager feature has not been enabled".

I've added a couple different types of config files to the test project hoping that would wire up everything, but it doesn't seem to like it.

How do I wire up a config file with all the provider information to the test project properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I simply had to add the configuration items to an App.config file instead of a Web.config file. I had just moved all the provider elements over by copying the Web.config. I just copied/pasted into App.config in my test project instead and it worked just fine after that.

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled here from google, for my asp.net web app I needed to enable roleManager in web.config, this sample is for using windows authentication/roles. Hope it  helps someone else.

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<identity impersonate="true" />
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"/>
```